# Wordpress load php content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make this panel work:
[image]

The elements on the left are `h4` with a data-* attribute that contains the post category that they have to load via `$.ajax();` in the middle section. there i display just the `the_post_thumbnail();` with a simple `php` loop. 
Then on clicking on one img I want to load the details of the post via `$.ajax();` on the box on the right.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h4.homus-partners-global-ajax').click(function() {
    var pb_cat = $(this).data('pb-cat');
    $('section').append(pb_cat);

    $.ajax({

      // type: "POST",
      // url: "wp-content/themes/homus-theme/loop_"+ pb_cat+".php",


      success: function(result) {

        $('ul.homus-partners-section-slide').html(result);

        $('section').append(result);
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```css
section.homus-partners {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 150px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 480px;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners {
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list {
  max-width: 170px;
  background-color: #a21c26;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex: 4;
  -ms-flex: 4;
  flex: 4;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list {
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 40px;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 30px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap {
    margin: 10px 30px;
    max-width: 480px;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 3px 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax {
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:hover::before,
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:active::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  top: 25%;
  left: -15px;
  content: "";
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:hover::before {
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:active::before {
  border-left: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:hover::before,
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:active::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    left: calc(50% - 5px);
    top: auto;
    bottom: -5px;
    content: "";
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  }
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:hover::before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-list .homus-partners-wrap h4.homus-partners-global-ajax:active::before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section {
  background-color: #c22633;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 3;
  -ms-flex: 3;
  flex: 3;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 490px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section {
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 140px;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section {
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partner-section-arrow-left,
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partner-section-arrow-right {
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 10px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partner-section-arrow-left i,
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partner-section-arrow-right i {
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 460px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner ul.homus-partners-section-slide {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: auto !important;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner ul.homus-partners-section-slide .homus-partners-section-single {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner ul.homus-partners-section-slide .homus-partners-section-single:last-of-type {
  padding: 0;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner ul.homus-partners-section-slide .homus-partners-section-single img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner ul.homus-partners-section-slide .homus-partners-section-single img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-section .homus-partners-section-inner ul.homus-partners-section-slide .homus-partners-section-single img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis {
  max-width: 310px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  -ms-flex: 2;
  flex: 2;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #c22633;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis {
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 140px;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-img {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-img {
    width: 30%;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-img img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-img img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-info {
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-info {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-info h4 {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #c22633;
}
section.homus-partners .homus-partners-detalis .homus-partners-detalis-info p {
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="homus-partners">
  <div class="homus-partners-list">
    <div class="homus-partners-wrap">
      <h4 class="homus-partners-global-ajax" data-pb-cat="pb_partner">
        partners
      </h4>
      <h4 class="homus-partners-global-ajax" data-pb-cat="pb_ente">
        enti
      </h4>
      <h4 class="homus-partners-global-ajax" data-pb-cat="">
        associazioni
      </h4>
      <h4 class="homus-partners-global-ajax" data-pb-cat="pb_coll">
        collaborazioni
      </h4>
      <h4 class="homus-partners-global-ajax" data-pb-cat="pb_media">
        media
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="homus-partners-section uk-slidenav-position" data-uk-slider>

    <a class="homus-partner-section-arrow-left uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-contrast uk-slidenav-previous" data-uk-slider-item="previous">
      <i class="uk-icon-caret-left"></i>
    </a>

    <div class="homus-partners-section-inner uk-slider-container">

      <ul class="homus-partners-section-slide uk-slider uk-grid-width-medium-1-4">

        <div class="homus-partners-section uk-slidenav-position" data-uk-slider>

          <a class="homus-partner-section-arrow-left uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-contrast uk-slidenav-previous" data-uk-slider-item="previous">
            <i class="uk-icon-caret-left"></i>
          </a>

          <div class="homus-partners-section-inner uk-slider-container">

            <ul class="homus-partners-section-slide uk-slider uk-grid-width-medium-1-4">

              <li class="homus-partners-section-single">
                <img src="http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/images/content/mouse.jpg">
              </li>

              <li class="homus-partners-section-single">
                <img src="http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/images/content/mouse.jpg">
              </li>

              <li class="homus-partners-section-single">
                <img src="http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/images/content/mouse.jpg">
              </li>

              <li class="homus-partners-section-single">
                <img src="http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/images/content/mouse.jpg">
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>

          <a class="homus-partner-section-arrow-right uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-contrast uk-slidenav-next" data-uk-slider-item="next">
            <i class="uk-icon-caret-right"></i>
          </a>


        </div>

      </ul>

    </div>

    <a class="homus-partner-section-arrow-right uk-slidenav uk-slidenav-contrast uk-slidenav-next" data-uk-slider-item="next">
      <i class="uk-icon-caret-right"></i>
    </a>


  </div>

  <div class="homus-partners-detalis">
    <div class="homus-partners-detalis-img">
      <img src="http://www.domyownpestcontrol.com/images/content/mouse.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="homus-partners-detalis-info">
      <h4>Fenice Pool</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

This is the cose i'm working on but i cant append any img to try the ajax function neither load php content because the server respond with a 500 error

---

EDIT 
As asked I provide the php code

this is the code i want to replace

```
    <?php get_template_part('loop_pb_coll') ?>
```

and this is the ajax function loading the new code

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "wp-content/themes/homus-theme/loop_"+ pb_cat+".php",
  success: function(result){
    $('ul.homus-partners-section-slide').html('<?php get_template_part('+result+') ?>');
    $('footer').append(result);
  }
 });
```

This is the error i get 
[image]

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, so it sounds like it is a problem with your PHP script, please post that as well.

Comment: The ajax request getting a 500 error sounds like you'd need to check your ajax endpoint and investigate for an error there first.  Are you providing good data to the .php page?  If not, you'd need to check the data your sending and implement error handling at the endpoint.  What happens if you try and access that url directly in the browser?

Comment: @AdamKonieska if i try from the address i get a 404 but the url is correct

Comment: Can you replace your css code (as it is not really necessary to the question) with your php code used in the ajax call; as others have pointed out, it is the most likely cause of the 500.

Comment: @NicolaBertelloni if you're getting a 404 error by entering the url in the browser's address bar, then the url doesn't seem to be correct.  Can you share the URL you're trying to use as your AJAX endpoint?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error, you can see the url there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your header.php add this to declare your ajax url

```
<script>var ajaxURL = '<?php echo esc_js(admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));?>';</script>
```

then in your JS.

```
$(document).delegate('h4.homus-partners-global-ajax', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var pb_cat = $(this).data('pb-cat');
    var data = {
        'action': 'GetPost',
        catURL : "loop_"+ pb_cat,
    };
    $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(response) {
        $( 'ul.homus-partners-section-slide' ).html(response);
    });

  });
```

then in your functions.php

```
function GetPost(){
    $cat = $_POST['catURL'];
    get_template_part($cat);
    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_GetPost', 'GetPost');
add_action('wp_ajax_GetPost', 'GetPost');
```

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work. Can you explain me the code that you want me to put in the header?

Comment: I modified it slightly

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a specific way to handle ajax requests. It is bad practice to place external PHP scripts inside the WordPress structure. If needed put them in a place on the server which is outside the control of the WordPress .htaccess.

WordPress functions anyway will not work within this script if you do not include wp-blog-header.php (which will trigger the bootstrap process of WordPress).

You can handle Ajax requests from within your theme or within a custom plugin you create.

The correct way to handle Ajax requests in WordPress is extensivley described in the WordPress codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

**Option 1:** Create a custom Plugin and use the functions as described in the codex

**Option 2:** Use the ajax functions as described in the codex in a custom Theme or Child Theme

**Option 3:** Create an external PHP file outside the WordPress folder structure on your server structure and make an ajax call to this external script.

Option 1 and 2 are good practice in terms of migration.

Comment: But that is not a plugin. You think I should transform it in a plugin?

Comment: Plugin is option 1. Option 2: Inside your Theme (if it is custom, same functions as described). Option 3: Make a folder outside WordPress, if needed load WordPress externally and your Ajax should work, too.

Comment: The answer of @Mark describes Option 2 in more detail.